# Removing or renaming swift in laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

The error I am getting is

> file: "/var/www/html/goalline/swiftmailer333/Swift.php" line: 32
>   message: "Cannot redeclare class Swift" type:
>   "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException"

I have a need to remove Swift from Laravel as it conflicts with functions form a legacy application that my Laravel app needs to call.

How can I do this? Whether I should is irrelevant I have to use those functions from the legacy application.

I've tried commenting 
`'Mail' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',`
and `'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider'` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to namespace your Swift class:

```
<?php 

namespace YourApp;

class Swift {

}
```

Then use it this way:

```
$swift = new YourApp\Swift;
```

Another possibility is to create a **nasty hack** to remove it from your Laravel installation, but to do that you'll have to create a repository of your own and use your repository in your composer.json file:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/yourusername/swiftmailer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Your repository can pretty much be a copy of swiftmailer's which you basically remove every file except the composer.json.

Comment: Namespacing I'd have to change all of Swift wouldn't I?

The entire platform is a nasty hack I'm not sure another would really hurt at this point

Comment: Not really, you basically will have to change that add a namespace to your Swift class and use the namespaced class wherever you have a Swift usage today. Everything else you can basically keep the way it is. It's a smaller hack :)

Comment: Namespacing a class is like changing its name from Swift to YourNamespaceSwify, the difference are the bars `\`, which are almost only   a visual difference.

Comment: So the issue I have when adding a namespace is I get further errors like "Class 'mynamespace\Swift_ClassLoader' not found"

Comment: Oh. That's part of the problem they're both swiftmailer and I pretty much have to leave them intact. 

Trying the nuclear approach of replacing Swift with NotSwift in the legacy app if that fails I'll try the repo.

Comment: They are both swift, but if you change yours you can control the next usages of it, and you don't have to change other files in the vendor folder.